# Background image link by data array

Tags: cytoscape.js

I get this error in cytoscape.js:

"Do not assign mappings to elements without corresponding data (e.g. ele `p` for property `background-image` with data field `linkImagem`); try a `[linkImagem]` selector to limit scope to elements with `linkImagem` defined"

Look data array:

```
{ data: { id: 'atr1', classificacao : '1', backgroundColor : '#F79646', nomeAtributo : 'Bancos desconfortáveis', angulo : '0', valign : 'top', halign : 'right', linkImagem : 'http://www.fec.unicamp.br/~confterm/imagens/background/nodes/8.png' }, position: { x:220, y: 300 }, selected: false, selectable: false, locked: false, grabbable: false }
```

Look script style options:

```
.selector('node')
          .css({
            'label': 'data(nomeAtributo)',
            'text-valign': 'data(valign)',
        'text-halign': 'data(halign)',
            'color' : '#000',
            'font-size': '11px',
            'background-fit': 'fit',
            'background-color': 'data(backgroundColor)',
            'background-image': 'data(linkImagem)',
          })
```

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is given to you in the error message.  Either don't use mappers if you're not going to define the data for each matching element, or adjust your selectors so that they only match elements with the data defined.

Comment: Tks Max, very helpful!