# How to make edges via drag and drop between two node with egdehandles extension in cytospace.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, cytoscape.js

I have a problem. I know, that this problem is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927020/background-image-link-by-data-array), but I don't know how show it in JS code.
I have

```
   style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
 .selector('node')
   .css({
   'shape': 'data(faveShape)',
   'background-color': 'data(faveColor)',
    'content': 'data(name)',
    'text-valign': 'center',
    'color': 'white',
    'text-outline-width': 2,
    'text-outline-color': '#888',
    'width': 100,
    'height':65
   })
```

and I create nodes by this code

```
 elements: {
nodes: [
  { data: { id: 'k', name: 'Kramer','faveColor': '#6FB1FC', 'faveShape' : 'roundrectangle'} },
  { data: { id: 'g', name: 'George','faveColor': '#6FB1FC', 'faveShape' : 'roundrectangle'} }
],
```

Error: Do not assign mappings to elements without corresponding data (e.g. ele `ele3` for property `shape` with data field `faveShape`); try a `[faveShape]` selector to limit scope to elements with `faveShape` defined

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my silly question. I solved the problem by changing parameter `handleLineType` to `straight`.

Comment: That works because you no longer have an edge preview, just a line instead.  Follow the instructions in the error message and you won't have an issue.  You shouldn't be using universal selectors like `node` if you want to use UI extensions.